# Caption at foot of long tables ('longtable' package)

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I would like to ask a question about `longtable` package. I've already posted it in other forums.

I have a long table (a several-pages-long one) using `longtable` package and I would like to add a table caption at the bottom of every piece of table, but a different one in the FIRST page.

`longtable` package allows a different "header" in the first page of the table (`\endfirsthead`) and/or a different "footer" in the LAST page of the table (`\endlastfoot`). What I would like to do is a different foot caption in the FIRST page of the table.

My example would be something like this:

First page table foot caption: "Table 1.2: Table description and so, and so...".

Following page table foot captions: "Table 1.2 (contd.): Table description and so, and so...".

It is similar to the example available at the documentation of `longtable` package about the usage of `\endfirsthead`, but I want to put it at the bottom of the tables because captions for all figures and tables in my document are at the foot, not at the head.

Is it so strange what I want to do?? How can I do it with `longtable`?

I would be very grateful if you could give me any hint or tip.

Thank you in advance for your answers!   :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the following example. That adds `\endfirstfoot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@firstfoot
\def\endfirstfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firstfoot}
\newdimen\LT@footdiff
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@
  \vskip\LTpre\endgraf
  \LT@footdiff-\ht\LT@foot
  \advance\LT@footdiff\ht\LT@firstfoot
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firstfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@firstfoot\fi
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
      \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
      \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
  \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
    \ifvoid\LT@foot
    \else
      \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
      \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
      \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
      \maxdepth\z@
    \fi
  \else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@firstfoot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}%
}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi  
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht   
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \else
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\box\LT@firstfoot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\advance\@colroom\LT@footdiff
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \fi
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}
\hline first head\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline head\\\hline\endhead
\hline first foot\\\hline\endfirstfoot
\hline (continued)\\foot\\\hline\endfoot
\hline last foot\\\hline\endlastfoot
A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\G\\H\\I\\J\\K\\L\\M\\N\\O\\P\\Q\\R\\S\\T\\U\\V\\W\\X\\Y\\Z\\
a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j\\k\\l\\m\\n\\o\\p\\q\\r\\s\\t\\u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z\\
0\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

---

## Addendum by Skillmon:

The above approach will use the normal `foot` instead of the `firstfoot` if the `longtable` will only take a single page and `lastfoot` wasn't used. The following is almost identical to the above code, but it will use the `firstfoot` on a single page `longtable`.

The precedence for the footer on a single page `longtable` will be:

1. `lastfoot`, and if that's empty
2. `firstfoot`, and if that's empty
3. `foot`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@firstfoot
\def\endfirstfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firstfoot}
\newdimen\LT@footdiff
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@
  \vskip\LTpre\endgraf
  \LT@footdiff-\ht\LT@foot
  \advance\LT@footdiff\ht\LT@firstfoot
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firstfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@firstfoot\fi
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
      \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
      \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
  \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
    \ifvoid\LT@foot
    \else
      \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
      \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
      \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
      \maxdepth\z@
    \fi
  \else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@firstfoot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}%
}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi  
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht   
      \vbox
        {%
          \unvbox\z@
          \box
            \ifvoid\LT@lastfoot
              \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
                \LT@foot
              \else
                \LT@firstfoot
              \fi
            \else
              \LT@lastfoot
            \fi
        }%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \else
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\box\LT@firstfoot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\advance\@colroom\LT@footdiff
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \fi
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}
\hline first head\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline head\\\hline\endhead
\hline first foot\\\hline\endfirstfoot
\hline (continued)\\foot\\\hline\endfoot
\hline last foot\\\hline\endlastfoot
A\\B\\C\\D\\E\\F\\G\\H\\I\\J\\K\\L\\M\\N\\O\\P\\Q\\R\\S\\T\\U\\V\\W\\X\\Y\\Z\\
a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\\j\\k\\l\\m\\n\\o\\p\\q\\r\\s\\t\\u\\v\\w\\x\\y\\z\\
0\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used this and added `\label` into the first footer. The links are generated correctly, but they don't work under `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) recently (in version 2021L) added support for long tables with these templates: `firsthead`, `firstfoot`, `middlehead`, `middlefoot`, `lasthead` and `lastfoot`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{head}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlefoot,lastfoot}{default}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}
}
\SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{blue3}
\SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red3}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Long Long Long Long Long Tabular},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {XXX}, width = \linewidth,
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1
}
\hline
 \SetRow{purple7} Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 \SetRow{purple7} Head & Head & Head \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 \SetRow{blue7} Foot & Foot & Foot \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why the command \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\midrule\footnotesize\textit{Continued on next page}}, doens't work?