# Underfull \vbox in each longtable... can it be fixed or must it be ignored?

Tags: boxes, longtable

I got some strange "underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line ..." warnings, obviously at each of my "longtable"s. Is there a way to fix them (I actually don't see the cause) or do I have to ignore them?

Minimal working example (PdfLaTeX tells these warnings triply for each run on compiling with `longtable [2000/10/22 v4.10 Multi-page Table package (DPC)]`; each `\demounderfullvbox` might be replaced by the full example code or the source may be reduced to one `longtable`, what doesn't change behavior):

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\demounderfullvbox}{%
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2in}|}
    %
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \hline\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{\ldots continued from previous page}}\\*
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{will be continued on next page\ldots}}\\*
    \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %
    \hline%
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2\\
    \end{longtable}
}

\begin{document}
\newpage
%
\demounderfullvbox
\demounderfullvbox
\demounderfullvbox

\end{document}
```

If `tabular` is used instead of `longtable`, no warnings occur, but that doesn't solve the problem, as much more rows can be placed in the tables.

Removing the trailing `\\` in the `aaaa:` line has no effect either.

The "underfull \vbox" warnings seem to specify a source line that looks ok to me (this is more clearly when `\demounderfullvbox` is replaced by the example code), think the warning is provocated on computation of first LTchunk?

Thanks for help and suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The underfull box is in fact the `\hline` at the start of the table (entered just after `\endlastfoot`)

If instead you remove it from there and put it at the end of the first head, as below, it all works out.

The reason for this eludes me at present but I'm sure it is all explained in detail in the package documentation......

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\showboxdepth10
\showboxbreadth10

\newcommand{\demounderfullvbox}{%
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{2in}|}
        \hline%
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{\ldots continued from previous page}}
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{will be continued on next page\ldots}}\\
    \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2
    \end{longtable}%
}

\begin{document}
\newpage
%
\demounderfullvbox
\demounderfullvbox
\demounderfullvbox

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops - that simple `\hline` position was it... I must have moved it some days ago with the intent to have all "data" rows with the same source layout, but haven't recognized the side effect... Thank you very much for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 7):

The example can be simplified to

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}[2004/02/01]
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{l}
    \hline
    x
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The `.log` file contains:

```
Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
[...]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 10

\vbox(8.39996+0.0)x345.0
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(0.4+0.0)x345.0, glue set 163.8611fill
..\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fill
..\hbox(0.4+0.0)x17.27782, glue set 17.27782fill
...\leaders 0.0 plus 1.0fill
....\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
..\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fill
```

Package `longtable` splits its contens in chunks (in `\LT@start`):

```
\dimen@ii\vfuzz
\vfuzz\maxdimen
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
\vfuzz\dimen@ii
```

Because of `\unvbox\tw@` it does not matter if the splitted box by `\vsplit` is too large or too small. `\setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}` sets the box in its natural size. Overfull boxes are catched by `\vfuzz`.  If `\hline` starts the table, then `\hline` and the next line is too large for `\ht\@arstrutbox`. But the line itself is too small for `\ht\@arstrutbox` and generates the underfull `\vbox`.

BTW, the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) says:

> Also \hline may be used, as in tabular.

Therefore I consider this behavior as bug that can be
fixed by setting `\vbadness` to `10000`, see lines marked with `(added)`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@\vskip\LTpre
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\LT@foot
  \edef\restore@vbadness{\vbadness\the\vbadness\relax}% (added)
  \vbadness=\@M % (added)
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
    \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
    \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \restore@vbadness % (added)
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
        \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
        \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@foot\else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd spotted the first bit but ran out of time checking if it would be safe just to silence the warning. I guess an update is called for...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed. Also feel free to consider [Caption at foot of long tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68448/16967) as feature request :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: maybe I've found another [problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72921/18439) in the apart from that brilliant `longtable`.

Comment: Yes saw that, been too busy to look this week, may have to be the weekend, or if you are lucky @HeikoOberdiek may fix it for you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: could you find some time to add Heiko's patch please?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is this going to be fixed or is there an issue with Heikos fix?

Comment: @Arsenal fixed in the sources for longtable 4.15 https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/4ff763f6d309c61dfd46cba2d66944cad5395dd4

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hope you were not holding your breath