# Faulty page-break in longtable: starts with endfoot

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

while intensively using the `longtable` environment, I ran into a situation where a the table is broken to the next page immediately after its `endfoot` line, without any real table row on the starting page. How to fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}[2004/02/01]

\begin{document}
\vspace*{188mm}

Here nearly at bottom of page, a longtable follows\ldots
\begin{longtable}{|l|p{58mm}|}
%
\hline
\endfirsthead
%
\hline\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{\ldots continued from previous page}}
\endhead
%
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{will be continued on next page\ldots}}\\*
\hline
\endfoot
%
\hline
\endlastfoot
%
aa: & 4711\\
\hline%
aaa: & 2\\
\hline%
aaaa: & 4711-2\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I'm going to create many documents automatically and therefore may not see such layout problems.

If the initial vertical space is a bit less or more, the problem disappears...

Thanks in advance for help and ideas!

Comment: It can experimentally be found that the critical minimum length is `\vspace*{187.212502mm}` for this example, at least in my envrionment. I don't know why and what that tells...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: with `\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}` the problem disappears in this MWE (the minimum length then is `\vspace*{189.338523mm}`), but that seems to be not always a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, `\usepackage{needspace}` may be added to declare the minimum space for, say, 2 table rows (one data row and the continuation message).

Just add `\newdimen\LTpreNeededspace` once and the following code before each `\begin{longtable}`:

```
\setlength{\LTpreNeededspace}{\baselineskip}\addtolength{\LTpreNeededspace}{\arrayrulewidth}
%\showthe\LTpreNeededspace
\multiply\LTpreNeededspace by 2 % Request 2 table lines, each including single '\hline', to fit on a page
%\showthe\LTpre
\addtolength{\LTpreNeededspace}{\dimexpr\LTpre - \glueshrink\LTpre\relax}\addtolength{\LTpreNeededspace}{\arrayrulewidth}   % Additionally, request the top '\hline' and the minimum value of '\LTpre'.
\addtolength{\LTpreNeededspace}{2.2pt}  % The reason for this necessary add-on is not yet clear.
\Needspace{\LTpreNeededspace}
```

Comment: `\setlength{\LTpreNeededspace}{\dimexpr\LTpre - \glueshrink\LTpre\relax}` should do (assuming that the shrink component is finite, of course).

Comment: Edit: added the `\dimexpr` term as suggested by egreg and removed last paragraph including [this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17349/is-there-a-way-to-measure-the-remaining-space-of-a-line-of-text). Thanks! All my trials with boxes didn't lead to this target (to compute `8.0pt` from the default `12.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 4.0pt` of `LTpre`)...

Comment: Edit: added another `2.2pt` to the requested length (`2.13pt` were identified as minimum); compare with the critical minimum `\vspace*` value posted as comment to the question.