# top-of-page positioning: \longtable vs. \tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable

Why is a `longtable` environment on top of pages vertically placed different to a `tabular` environment? I'm digging several days on this question and didn't find a way to align the `longtable` vertically in the same way.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque iaculis nunc eget congue. Etiam lobortis nisi velit. Proin tristique massa a lectus ullamcorper semper. Aenean ut dignissim diam. Integer ullamcorper eros nibh. Cras molestie neque quis lectus lobortis egestas. Maecenas vel tortor in nulla sagittis venenatis. Nulla ac eros dui, eget lacinia ante. Fusce elementum nisl ac tortor hendrerit id lacinia orci malesuada. Praesent eu iaculis mi. Vestibulum sodales tempor rutrum. }
\newcommand{\examplelongtable}{%
    \begin{longtable}{|l|p{58mm}|}
    %
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \hline\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{\ldots continued}}
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{will be continued\ldots}}\\*
    \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2\\
    \end{longtable}
}
\newcommand{\exampletabular}{%
    \begin{tabular}[H]{|l|p{58mm}|}
    \hline
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.0\baselineskip}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTleft}{\parindent}

\begin{document}
\exampletabular

\lorem

\lorem

\lorem

\lorem

\lorem
\examplelongtable
\end{document}
```

Supposedly there is a very simple solution, but I seem to be unable to find it...

If I explicitly set a `\newpage` before the `longtable` example, an adapted `\vspace*{-...}` would help, but not on a regular page-break, where the source code doesn't "know" where it occurs.

Comment: There is no `[H]` option to `tabular`. If you use `[t]`, instead, the alignment will be the same.

Comment: @egreg The additional rules and box levels interfere with `\topskip`. The top element in the table, the top line, is aligned with the baseline of the first line in the text body. In the case of `longtable`. Here the first header box has height 0.4pt because of the rule. Then 10.6pt of `\topskip` (11pt) are added.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes there ought to be some option of controlling the position of the head really. (Well if you know what you are doing you can \noalign some negative space into the head, but it could be easier.

Comment: +1 @egreg: that's true, I must have been confused with `table` and `float` package. At the top, both tables are equally aligned with `\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|p{58mm}|}` - but, can anyone explain, why not at bottom, too? Putting one more `\lorem` at the end shows about 5.0pt more distance than below `tabular`...

Comment: @tueftl There is a big difference between a `[t]` `tabular` and a `longtable`; a `[t]` `tabular` is set in a `\halign` wrapped in a `\vtop`, which means that only the first row contributes to the height of the box, the rest is depth; thus the interline glue after this `tabular` will quite certainly be `\lineskip`. On the contrary, `longtable` makes only the `\halign`, so that each row contributes autonomously to height and depth.

Comment: The more far I get to the target (replaceability of `tabular` and `longtable`), the more it's getting intricated and I'm tinkering with the idea to give up :-( Now the `\noalign{\kern-\topskip}` before `\hline\endfirsthead` seems to be completely ignored... @DavidCarlisle No, I don't know exactly what I'm doing there and if that is correct. Maybe I'll try to get a MWE from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going into depth, I experimentally found the following, which only works with a `0pt` `\topskip` and outside-bordered tables: there are different measures to be applied prior to the tables depending on what precedes which kind of table. Only if `tabular` follows `tabular`, nothing is to be added. So all distances are as if only `tabular` would be used (note: without `table` environment, so not floating, just in place).

The code is tested with different values of `\parskip` and `\arrayrulewidth` (EDIT: and `\lineskip`). Accuracy is about 0.05pt. The two table variants are exchangeable, page breaks work (everything is vertically aligned equally to the upper page border).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque iaculis nunc eget congue. Etiam lobortis nisi velit. Proin tristique massa a lectus ullamcorper semper. Aenean ut dignissim diam. Integer ullamcorper eros nibh. Cras molestie neque quis lectus lobortis egestas. Maecenas vel tortor in nulla sagittis venenatis. Nulla ac eros dui, eget lacinia ante. Fusce elementum nisl ac tortor hendrerit id lacinia orci malesuada. Praesent eu iaculis mi. Vestibulum sodales tempor rutrum. }
\newcommand{\examplelongtable}{%
    \begin{longtable}[H]{|l|p{58mm}|}
    %
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \hline\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{\ldots continued}}
    \endhead
    %
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsl{will be continued\ldots}}\\*
    \hline
    \endfoot
    %
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    %
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2\\
    \end{longtable}
}
\newcommand{\exampletabular}{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|p{58mm}|}
    \hline%
    aa: & 4711\\
    \hline%
    aaa: & 2\\
    \hline%
    aaaa: & 4711-2\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.0\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{\dimexpr\lineskip-6.0pt\relax}  % If '\lineskip' (or the whichever 6.0pt measure) would be changed after this line, '\LTpost' would become out of date.
\setlength{\LTleft}{\parindent}

\lorem

\newpage

%\lorem

\vspace{-\parskip}
\exampletabular

\vspace{\dimexpr\parskip+\lineskip\relax}%  % Only if 'tabular' is followed by a 'longtable'.
\examplelongtable

\vspace{\dimexpr\parskip+6.0pt\relax}%  % Only if 'longtable' is followed by another 'longtable'.
\examplelongtable

\vspace{\dimexpr\arrayrulewidth-7.57pt\relax}%  % Only if 'longtable' is followed by a 'tabular'.
\exampletabular

\exampletabular

\vspace{\dimexpr\parskip+\lineskip\relax}%  % Only if 'tabular' is followed by a 'longtable'.
\examplelongtable

\lorem

\lorem

\lorem

\vspace{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\arrayrulewidth-2.08pt\relax}%    % Only if text is followed by a 'longtable'.
\examplelongtable

\lorem
\end{document}
```

Note that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72921/18439) regarding `longtable` at page breaks might be of interest also.

Does anyone know the origin resp. name of the `6.0pt` measure, or any of the other two twisted measures?