# Longtable caption below table in LyX

Tags: lyx, longtable

In LyX I've created a longtable. In LyX the caption is below the table but in the PDF it is shown above the table. Is there a way to force the caption to be below the table in the PDF without converting the table to LaTeX code?

Thanks.

Comment: A `longtable` is a table that might span several pages. A caption at the end means the reader would have to read pages before he knows what the purpose or the table is.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I agree - but it will still break the style consistency with the rest of the document (hence it will just get returned to me with a comment as such). I may leave it at the top for now, but I'd be interested to know if any one has ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

A longtable is a table that might span several pages. A caption at the end means the reader would have to read pages before he knows what the purpose or the table is.

Nevertheless there are several ways to put the caption at the end of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l}
a\\
b\\
\caption{Table caption}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{l}
\caption{Table caption}
\endlastfoot
a\\
b\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

(I am not familiar with LyX, therefore I can only provide LaTeX code.)

The same caption can be repeated on each page by using `\endfoot` instead of `\endlastfoot` in the latter example.

It is also possible to set the caption in the first foot and the other captions have some text added like "continued", see [**Caption at foot of long tables**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68439/16967).