# 'longtable' and 'booktabs' not working on this example?

Tags: longtable, booktabs

I am not even sure what is wrong here. I have a table I would like the caption to be at bottom, marked with (continued) from 2nd page onwards. I would like the table to break at certain places by using `\\` instead of `\\*`. Finally, the `booktab` command `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` should be used at top and bottom at each page.

What surprises me is even with `\pagebreak` or `\newpage` the table still refuse to break across pages.

The example table, with desired breakpoints marked with red arrows.
[image: The example table]

## Code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,longtable,booktabs}
%Add \endfirstfoot support http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68439/caption-at-foot-of-long-tables-longtable-package
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@firstfoot
\def\endfirstfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firstfoot}
\newdimen\LT@footdiff
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@
  \vskip\LTpre
  \LT@footdiff-\ht\LT@foot
  \advance\LT@footdiff\ht\LT@firstfoot
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firstfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@firstfoot\fi
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
      \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
      \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
  \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
    \ifvoid\LT@foot
    \else
      \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
      \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
      \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
      \maxdepth\z@
    \fi
  \else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@firstfoot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}%
}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi  
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht   
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \else
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\box\LT@firstfoot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\advance\@colroom\LT@footdiff
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \fi
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[!hp]
  \centering
    \begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule \endfirsthead 
    \toprule \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tbl:ch7a_config}\\% 
    \endfirstfoot
    \bottomrule
    \caption[]{(continued)}\\% 
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \caption[]{(continued)}\\%     
    \endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{1}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{2}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{3}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{4}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{5}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{6}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{7}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{8}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{9}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{10}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{11}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{12}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{13}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{14}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{15}\end{sideways} \\*
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{16}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{17}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{18}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{19}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{20}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{21}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{22}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{23}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{24}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{25}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{26}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{27}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{28}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{29}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{30}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{31}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{32}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{33}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{34}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{35}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{36}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{37}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{38}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{39}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{40}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{41}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{42}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{43}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{44}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{45}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{46}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{47}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{48}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{49}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{50}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{51}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{52}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{53}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{54}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{55}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{56}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{57}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{58}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{59}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{60}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{61}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{62}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{63}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{64}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{65}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{66}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{67}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{68}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{69}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{70}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{71}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{72}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{73}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{74}\end{sideways} & \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 
    \end{longtable}%      
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you take it out of the `\begin{table}` `\end{table}` pair it will break.

Answer (score 2):

By placing the `longtable` in a float you're preventing it from breaking across pages.  In addition, I believe that `longtables` are centered by default, so you don't need `\centering`.  To let `longtable` do its job, just remove the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` pair (and the `\centering` command):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,longtable,booktabs}
%Add \endfirstfoot support http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68439/caption-at-foot-of-long-tables-longtable-package
\makeatletter
\newbox\LT@firstfoot
\def\endfirstfoot{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@firstfoot}
\newdimen\LT@footdiff
\def\LT@start{%
  \let\LT@start\endgraf
  \endgraf\penalty\z@
  \vskip\LTpre
  \LT@footdiff-\ht\LT@foot
  \advance\LT@footdiff\ht\LT@firstfoot
  \dimen@\pagetotal
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
  \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firstfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@firstfoot\fi
  \dimen@ii\vfuzz
  \vfuzz\maxdimen
  \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
  \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
  \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
  \vfuzz\dimen@ii
  \advance\dimen@ \ht
      \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@\dp
      \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
  \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
  \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
  \global\@colroom\@colht
  \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
    \ifvoid\LT@foot
    \else
      \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
      \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
      \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
      \maxdepth\z@
    \fi
  \else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@firstfoot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@firstfoot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
  \fi
  \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\copy\LT@head\else\box\LT@firsthead\fi\nobreak
  \output{\LT@output}%
}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
      \fi  
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht   
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifvoid\LT@firstfoot
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \else
      \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\box\LT@firstfoot\vss}%
      \@makecol
      \@outputpage
      \global\advance\@colroom\LT@footdiff
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \fi
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
    \toprule \endfirsthead 
    \toprule \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Add caption}\label{tbl:ch7a_config}\\% 
    \endfirstfoot
    \bottomrule
    \caption[]{(continued)}\\% 
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \caption[]{(continued)}\\%     
    \endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{1}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{2}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{3}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{4}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{5}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{6}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{7}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{8}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{9}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{10}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{11}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{12}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{13}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{14}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{15}\end{sideways} \\*
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{16}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{17}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{18}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{19}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{20}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{21}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{22}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{23}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{24}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{25}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{26}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{27}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{28}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{29}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{30}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{31}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{32}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{33}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{34}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{35}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{36}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{37}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{38}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{39}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{40}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{41}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{42}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{43}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{44}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{45}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{46}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{47}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{48}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{49}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{50}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{51}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{52}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{53}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{54}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{55}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{56}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{57}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{58}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{59}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{60}\end{sideways} \\* \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1 \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2 \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{ID}} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{61}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{62}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{63}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{64}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{65}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{66}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{67}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{68}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{69}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{70}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{71}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{72}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{73}\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}\textbf{74}\end{sideways} & \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Zeros}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{z1} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z2} & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z34} & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{z56} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Poles}\end{sideways}}} & \textit{p1} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p2} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p34} & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     &  \\*
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textit{p56} & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 1     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 2     & 1     & 2     & 
    \end{longtable}%    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah sorry about the silly question, didn't know that at all!

Comment: There is a problem with it though, it seems to be breaking the page at the last block with titles, even though I put `\\* \midrule ...`. Removing `\midrule` solves the problem. What gives?

Comment: Hey Mobius, as far as I can tell, the `\\*` command disallows page breaking on the next row.  Your next row is the `\midrule` so the page can be broken again after the `\midrule`.  You could also try `\\*\midrule\\*`

Comment: Also, it's not a silly question...that's an easy enough thing to miss :)